# How to filter json list in python

Tags: python, json

I have json format list like this :

```
[('{ "header1": "Subject", "header2": "Text"}',)]
[(' { "condition1": "Equal", "condition2": "Contain"}',)]
[('{ "parameter1": "hi1", "parameter2": "hi2",)]
```

What i trying to do here is to combine header, condition and parameter together. For example the first condition should be header1 & condition1 & parameter1, and second condition should be header2 & condition2 & parameter2. (the header(index), condition(index), parameter(index) will be add dynamically if there is a new record, for example: `header3, condition3, parameter3`

Expected Output:

```
first condition: Subject Equal hi1
second condition: Text Contain hi2
```

So after i get these value i should able to parse the value to my function to filter things with the above first condition and second condition. Im trying to filter my email inbox with the above condition. For example: when incoming email `Subject` `Equal` to `hi1` it should `(print "work")` and when second incoming email that `Text` `Contain` `hi2` it should `(print "work")` too.

I come out with an idea on how the code structure should look, but i do not know how can I proceed to make the code works. Hope you guys understand my question and help me with any guidances thanks.

My idea code structure:

```
if 'headerDynamic' == 'Subject' or 'Text':
    if 'conditionDynamic' == 'Equal':
              'do Equal function'
    if 'conditionDynamic' == 'Contain':
              'do Contain function'
else :
    print('error')
```

Full Code:

```
#email inbox declaration (receiver)
EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "xxx@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "xxx"

#email
#Main function
class SendMail(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id_manager):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id_manager = int(id_manager)

    def run(self):

        while True:
            mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
            mail.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
            mail.list()
            mail.select('inbox')
            result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "UNSEEN")  # (ALL/UNSEEN)
            i = len(data[0].split())
            for x in range(i):
                latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
                result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
                # result, email_data = conn.store(num,'-FLAGS','\\Seen')
                # this might work to set flag to seen, if it doesn't already
                raw_email = email_data[0][1]
                raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
                email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

                # Header Details
                date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(email_message['Date'])
                if date_tuple:
                    local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
                    local_message_date = "%s" % (str(local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))
                    email_from = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['From'])))
                    email_to = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['To'])))
                    global subject
                    subject = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['Subject'])))

                # Body details
                for part in email_message.walk():

                    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                        body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                        print("From:", email_from)

                        print("Email To:", email_to)
                        print("date:", local_message_date)
                        print("Subject:", subject)
                        print("body:", body.decode('utf-8'))

                        #condition
                        
                        if 'headerDynamic' == 'Subject' or 'Text':
                            if 'conditionDynamic' == 'Equal':
                                'do Equal function'
                            if 'conditionDynamic' == 'Contain':
                                'do Contain function'
                        else :
                            print('error')

                    else:
                        continue


def mainSendEmail():
    thread_id = ("0")
    led_index = 0
    thread_list = list()
    for objs in thread_id:
        thread = SendMail(led_index)
        thread_list.append(thread)
        led_index += 1
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainSendEmail()
```

Comment: Why did you define the data structure like this? Wouldn't it be much simpler/ natural to have a object containing `header`, `condition` and `parameter` as those belong together, and have a `list` of those instead of having an object with a list of each.

Comment: That is not JSON

Comment: Can you update your "json" for us as that is not "json"

Comment: Please don't abandon questions like this. People want to help but can't as your input data is not a list but something else Is that three distinct data points? do you have json records perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing literal strings to each other, which cannot work:

```py
'headerDynamic' == 'Subject'
```

will always be false.

Also, the syntax for `or` operations is incorrect:

```py
'headerDynamic' == 'Subject' or 'Text'
```

will be `True` if `'Text'` is truthy, which it always is.

To compare dict values, you have to load the JSON into a dict:

```py
import json

headers = [('{ "header1": "Subject", "header2": "Text"}',)]
for header in headers:
    # get the json string
    json_str = header[0]
    # load it
    data = json.loads(json_str)
    # get the value
    if data["header1"] == "Subject" or data["header1"] == "Text":
        print("Do equal function.")
```

Comment: It showed `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loads'`

Comment: Ah yes, I shadowed the import. I fixed it, you can try again now.